# Recursive method implementation

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Imagine a row of n lights that can be turned on or off only under certain conditions as follows. The first light can be turned on or off anytime. Each of the other lights can be turned on or off only when the preceding light is on and all other lights before it are off. An example of turning off 3 lights is as following:

111

011

010

110

100

000

I am given the algorithm for turnOff() and I want to come up with algorithm for turning on.

```
turnOff(n)
   if(n = 1) turn off light 1
   else {
         if(n>2) turnOff(n-2)
         turn off light n
         if(n>2) turnOn(n-2)
         turnOff(n-1) 
        }
```

I tried to write algorithm for turning on the lights and came up with the following:

```
turnOn(n)
    if(n=1) turn on light 1
    else{
      if(n>2) turnOn(n-1)
      turn on n-1
      if(n>2) turnOff(n-2)
      turn on n
 }
```

But it doesn't work. I don't know how to think recursively. I don't know what am I suppose to do to figure it out.

My turnOn(3) gives me the following output:

[image]

Comment: Ummm there is no java in here, why the tag?

Comment: Also, what the heck. You are only left, with 1st light, which you can flip as you wish. What is your problem? It works.

Comment: Yes I can make the first one turned on. But that won't work with 4 or 5 or 6 lights.

Comment: Hmm, how can you turn off 4 lights (and more)?

Comment: @PhamTrung That's what I am asking. I can't figure it out.

Comment: Could you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the test cases to turn on odd and even number of lights:

For 3 lights:

000

100

110

010

011

111

For 4 lights:

0000

1000

1100

0100

0110

1110

1010

0010

0011

1011

1111

**Algorithm for turning on:**

1. Always turn up the first light first
2. Then turn on the second light
3. Then turn off first light to turn on third light
4. Turn on third light
5. Turn on first light again to turn of second light
6. Turn of second light
7. Turn off first light to turn on fourth light
8. Turn on fourth light

Our first goal will be always first to turn on the last light. Once, it is on, we can proceed forward. Now its on. Once clever decision will be not to turn off the light before the last light, once the last light is on.

In this way, at a time, we will be able to turn on 2 lights from end side.

If you have n number of lights, with one repetition, you will be able to turn on k=2 lights, now n-k numbers of lights remaining. Just repeat the process for those n-k lights as long as n-k=0/1

If n-k=0, your task is finished, all lights on.

Question:

If n-k=1, what will you do? Very easy, just try to guess!

Comment: I believe the OP want to turn all lights `off` not `on`, and for the last state, how can it be possible changing from 1011 to 1111 given that `light can be turned on or off only when the preceding light is on and all other lights before it are off`

Comment: As he said: "I am given the algorithm for turnOff() and I want to come up with algorithm for turning on.", I think he needs the algorithm to turn on the lights. He already has the algorithm to turn off the lights. And changing from 1011 to 1111 is just fine, because here you are just turning second light on and for this, the preceding first light is on and there are no other lights before.